# How to assign the state of a blinking LED in an always block in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have this code:

```
module(
// Set inputs and outputs
    output [7:0]ledg
);

reg state;

assign ledg[0] = state;

always @ (posedge clock)
begin
    // Increment a counter and set state <= to the counter
end

always @ (posedge clock)
if (sw[9:5] == 5'b00010)
begin
    hex3 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex2 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex1 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex0 <= 7'b1000000;
end

endmodule
```

I got the LED to blink, but what I want is to be able to have the LED blink when one of the sw[9:5] is ON. However, the way it's coded, the LED is always blinking whether the switch is on or off.

However I am having trouble with the line of code:

```
assign ledg[0] = state;
```

The problem, I believe, is that you cannot use the assign keyword in an always block. It has to be assigned outside an always block.

And this is where my problem lies. How do I assign the state of the blinking LED in such a way that it will "start" blinking when it enters the IF condition block, but stops blinking when the switch is down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag to create a conditional statement:

```
assign ledg[0] = (flag  == 1'b1) ? state : '0;
```

You need to change your always block to:

```
always @ (posedge clock)
if (sw[9:5] == 5'b00010)
begin
    flag <= 1'b1;
    hex3 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex2 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex1 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex0 <= 7'b1000000;
end
else begin
    flag <= 1'b0;
end
```

FYI, you could have used the values of hex0 to hex3, but you don't assign any values to them when the switch is not on. As a result they will synthesize to latches.

Alternatively, you can define ledg[0] as a reg, and just assign to it in the always block without the assign keyword:

```
module(
// Set inputs and outputs
    output reg [7:0]ledg // <----- 'output' to 'output reg'
);

reg state;

//assign ledg[0] = state; <-------Remove this line

always @ (posedge clock)
begin
    // Increment a counter and set state <= to the counter
end

always @ (posedge clock)
if (sw[9:5] == 5'b00010)
begin
    hex3 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex2 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex1 <= 7'b1000000;
    hex0 <= 7'b1000000;
    ledg[0] <= state;
end
else 
    ledg[0] <= '0;
endmodule
```